# Apache Camel - file transfer issue via smb endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

I've tried to get this to work by trying several endpoint combinations without much of luck.

The issue is that Camel doesn't seem to copy a modified file after being copied the first time to its destination. The route used is:

```
from("smb://networkDriveOne?noop=true&fileName=inputFile.csv")
  .to("smb://networkDriveTwo?fileExist=Override")
```

When Camel is restarted, the inputFile.csv file is copied to its destination as expected. When inputFile.csv modified and saved in the input directory, however, Camel doesn't pick it up and override the one in the destination.

Versions:

Camel: 2.14.0

ActiveMQ: 5.11.0

Spring MVC: 4.1.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue. Please see the [File2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) Documentation.

> **noop**: If true, the file is not moved or deleted in any way. This option is good for readonly data, or for ETL type requirements. If noop=true, Camel will set idempotent=true as well, to avoid consuming the same files over and over again.

But you can use the idempotent consumer to work for you.
Try this:

```
from("smb://networkDriveOne?noop=true&fileName=inputFile.csv
    &idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:modified}")
    .to("smb://networkDriveTwo?fileExist=Override")
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I've also placed the same question in Camel mailing list http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/smb-endpoint-modified-files-not-copied-to-destination-td5770499.html